# Given an array of different non integer values, how do I find the value where 99% of the data is above and value where 99% is below

Tags: distributions

I can easily find the min and the max of the list by going through the list,
But I can't seem to figure out how to get 99% of the min and 99% of the max.
I need this mainly because there are some spikes in data and I want to draw it without those spikes

I would think taking a weighted average of the entire distribution,
then dividing by the weight*99 would give me the 1% location, and weight/99 would give me the 99% location. Is this correct?

I am trying to solve the problem without sorting the array

Comment: Welcome to CV. You seem to be looking for [quantiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile), specifically the 1st and 99th percentile. How to go about that programmatically is off-topic on this site.

Comment: If you have the entire set of values then you can count the numbers, sort them in ascending or descending order and then count up and down from the ends by 1% of the total number of values. (You have not said what the "spikes" are. If they are the topic of the question then you need to be more explicit about that.)

Comment: trying to avoid sorting the data, yes quantiles are what Im looking for, however the data is not discreet

Comment: @PBulls I don't think discussion of algorithms for computing parameter estimates is off topic here; asking for code *can* be off topic.

Comment: @Mich There are algorithms for quantiles that avoid sorting.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid sorting? Is the data set huge? And why does the data not being discrete matter?